# how to compare arrays for additions and subtractions in php?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays:

```
$currentArr = ['apples','oranges','pears'];

$newArr = ['apples','oranges','pears', 'grapes'];
```

I need to formulate logic that will:

a) check the `$newArr` against the `$currentArr` and tell me what was REMOVED and what was ADDED

b) push the removed values onto a new separate array and push the added values onto a new separate array

as I am not extremely well versed in PHP, is this possible? if so, how can I do so?

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) might be usefull for that task! You can use that once in each direction and you have the desired output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) is what you need:

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
<?php

$currentArr = ['apples','oranges','pears','test'];
$newArr = ['apples','oranges','pears', 'grapes'];

$removed = array_diff($currentArr, $newArr);
print_r($removed);
// output: 
// Array ( [3] => test )

// switch the order to get the added items:
$added = array_diff($newArr, $currentArr);
print_r($added);
// output:
// Array ( [3] => grapes )
```

Comment: ahhhhh, of course... well my IQ dropped a few points here, ha! thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

arr_diff($a,$b) is a function that returns a new array containing the items in $a that are not in $b.

```
$removed = array_diff($currentAr,$newArr);
$added = array_diff($newArr,$currentAr);
```